# $\{f_n\}$ integrable functions and $\{g_n\}$ uniformly bounded sequence of continuous functions, then is the following statement true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $f$ be integrable functions on [0,1] such that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)| dx = 0$.

Then, is the following statement true?

If $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a function $g$ , then,

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 |f_n(x) g_n(x) - f(x) g(x) | dx \rightarrow 0 $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: If $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$, then there exists a subsequence and $g\in L^1$ such that $|f_{n_k}|\leq g$ for all $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Jose27 I have already shown that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ , as was asked in a previous part of the problem, but using your hint I cant see how do I progress.. so do I consider a sequence $g_n$ which pointwise converges to this $g$ which you mentioned and also satisfies $|g_n| \leq g$, such a sequence has to be uniformly convergent to $g$ (??) and so the product $f_n g_n$ satisfies $|f_n g_n| \leq g^2$ and by dominated convergence theorem $f_n g_n \rightarrow fg$ in $L^1$ ??? I think I am thinking wrong...?

Comment: Sorry, I used unfortunate notation in my previous comment. My $g$ should really be called $h$, it has nothing to do with the $g$ in the OP. Your idea is "broadly" correct: notice that by assumption $|g_n|\leq M$ for some $M$ and all $n$, then the idea is to use dominated convergence as you said (though a subtle point is that you'll only be able to apply it on a subsequence, and you'll have to upgrade this to the full sequence).

Comment: @Jose27 ok now it certainly makes more sense, as $|f_{n_k} g_n| \leq gM $ for this subsequence, but I can't recall any theorem/result which will help me lift this convergence to the entire sequence of $f_n g_n$ , could you please complete your answer , may be you can write an answer separately, so I can accept it (i can't upvote)..thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\int | f_ng_n -fg| &\leq \int | f_n g_n - fg_n| + \int |f g_n -fg|\\
& \leq M \int |f_n-f| + \int |f| |g_n-g|
\end{align*}
where $M = \sup ||g_n||_\infty$. Furthermore, $| g_n -g| |f| \to 0$ almost everywhere, and it is dominated by an integrable function. Can you finish the proof? (apply dominated convergence thm)